# Moving an External USB HDD containing my main Ubuntu 22 system to a better computer with greater Hardware ...?

Tags: boot, uefi, 22.04, intel, amd-ryzen

*So here's my issue:*

I've got my Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a 2TB External USB HDD and ...

Soon in a few or so hours a *pre-built* computer is on it's way over here and The system I am using currently has got the hardware from 2013 specifically,

An **Intel Core i3** and **4 Gigs of RAM** and **Integrated Graphics**.

which by 2022 standards is struggling by a big margin. and so I was hoping to **just move** ![My External USB HDD *"WD 2 TB My Passport"*] (https://photos.app.goo.gl/xickmcjdQW2REkoB8) to a more average Spec computer such that it wont slow me down as much of present apps Cannot stay in peace with 4GB ram.

So the specs are :

CPU: Ryzen 5 3400 G

RAM: 16 GB DDR4

Graphics: Well I got an **APU** for a reason (AMD Integrated Graphics)

And motherboard : AsRock B450 Steel Legend

That's all for the spec comparison.

The System I am running is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy Jellyfish 64-bit EFI

**Now Here's What I tested:** Please do not read if you want some information bcoz it's just gibberish and maybe won't help much. But I included cos it's still information.

I went and unplugged it from the computer and plugged it into the laptop which is way better than any of the ones I compared to just before but is not mine so I don't have the courage to mess things on that laptop. it got an **Intel i7 8th gen, 16 GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce MX150 4GB GDDR5**.

What happened was i booted into the drive through boot menu and also enabled Legacy Support Mode in the BIOS Settings and it booted into your usual scanning that shows every time you boot **UBUNTU** something about *how many blocks registered* **eg. 300000000/1480000000 registered blocks** and then there's some sort of recovery and asks for my Root Password Which I *had forgotten* and had it changed after re plugging into the original computer and later again on the Laptop it asks for Root Pass and i input it in and soon after it says something was not found. and says type exit to restart.

Soon after i searched through the Forums and couldn't find any help for this situation.

Here's my final Question: *Is it possible for me to just move a disk containing Ubuntu onto another computer without Loosing any data on my part and still able to boot it just normally?*

**= Yes/No/Solution/Ask For More Info**

Also I am in High-school and i don't have much Idea about How OS's Boot and Grub And all.

**Computer has arrived**

Btw both computers have UEFI but I have installed EFI Operating systems for reasons.

The screen that comes up after being booted on another computer with different hardware.

[Just after booting into the ext. HDD from boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP9x8.jpg)

Comment: use clonezilla it can backup to a hard drive and then restore to a new one

Comment: here is a good tutorel https://www.linuxbabe.com/backup/how-to-use-clonezilla-live

Comment: Was old install Legacy/BIOS/CSM? Systems since 2012 are now UEFI since Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. If legacy it should boot, but is now an old configuration. If UEFI, you will have to reinstall grub, but more details required. And you may need nomodeset boot parameter or recovery mode boot until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu's repository.

Comment: So no the old system as said is also UEFI but for some issues regarding uefi dual boot with windows being a pain I made its main drive to work on efi meaning MBR partition instead of GPT. Also the dual boot is for win10 and Phoenix OS. The external drive is also on MBR as I think Ubuntu doesn't run on GPT ... Coz I found the issue of no more than 4 partitions allowed whilst using it.

Comment: Also lnee suggested to use clonezilla ... But I still don't want to junk the computer that came because it was custom built in my home town 6 months ago and has windows with a large amount of data. I want to keep my business clean. Also cannot just remove the files coz they are needed by someone else.

Comment: ~Oldfred, I have just uploaded an image for the screen I am getting.